# Passing data via segue and sqlite

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I am trying to pass some data from selected row via segue to another viewcontroller but I cannot. I tried almost everything, but I always get:

```
2016-06-16 18:41:20.069 Wine Dictionary[3282:55647] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<Wine_Dictionary.DetailUI: 0x7f8a1ae2fa60>) has no segue with identifier 'SegueToDetailUI''
```

I already tried changing method, changing identifier etc.

Here is the screenshot of the code: http://prntscr.com/bh6e6l
Here is the screenshot of the storyboard and segue identifier: http://prntscr.com/bh6f6q

Answer (score 0):

delete your code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and add this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
  if (segue.identifier == "SegueToDetailUI") {
    let selectedInfo = self.NAME?[indexPath.row]
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailUI
    destinationVC.programVar = selectedInfo!
  }
}
```

assuming I spelled everything correctly (if not just correct my spelling)

Comment: That way it works but it does not pass the required data. What should I do about that?

Comment: What do you mean it does not pass the required data? Are you getting an error that way?

Comment: No, in the DetailUI (which is second viewcontroller) I do not get info from clicked cell in the previous viewcontroller. My goal is to pass the name of the clicked cell and this way it just segues to another VC without passing it.

Comment: Ahh I'm know what's going on. Your code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` should be moved to `prepareForSegue`

Comment: I'm going to make an edit to show you what to change

Comment: Now it gives use of unresolved identifier indexpath :(

Comment: re-copy and paste, try that and let me know

Comment: "Use of local variable indexPath before its declaration"

Comment: I got it to work, but now it does not even segue to another vc, it just selects the row and stays at the same vc.

Comment: did you link the segue via the interface builder?

Comment: I did. Can I send you the project so you can check it out? - here it is https://www.sendspace.com/file/sy8kuw

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your segue and recreate it..

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if (segue.identifier == "SegueToDetailUI")
   {
    if let rowselect = tableView!.indexPathForSelectedRow        
        {
          let selectedInfo =self.NAME?[rowselect]
          let moveVC:DetailUI = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailUI
         moveVC.programVar = selectedInfo!  
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working. It just selects row and does nothing. http://prntscr.com/bh7uox

Comment: are u using the data received in DetailUI view controller? if possible post ur DetailUI view controller class code..

Comment: It doesnt matter but I do. It should still segue to DetailUI. http://prntscr.com/bh8e5a

Comment: I don't get any errors but it still doesn't work. It just selects row and does not segue to DetailUI. http://prntscr.com/bh7uox

Answer (score 0):

Since your segue goes from MainUI to DetailUI, performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueToDetailUI") musts be run from MainUI, the view controller at the origin of the segue.

Invoking this method will instantiate the DetailUI view controller, and push it on the screen.

Configuration of the newly created DetailUI view controller happens in the method MainUI.prepareForSegue. That's where you'll provide the programVar property.

*Remember*: when you use storyboards, you never never never instantiate view controllers yourself (`let vc = MyViewController()`). Instead, you'll always use one of the NSStoryboard.instantiateViewController... methods, or NSViewController.performSegue(...).

Comment: It is run from MainUI.

Comment: I don't get you. Would you be so kind to paste the code here so everyone can see please?